# android P2P IP socket communication

Tags: android, sockets, ip

I have developed android p2p ip socket communication app.
It works well on local internet.
But I can't test it on network. For example my android device ip is 192.168.1.101, and others 10.45.33.21.(other country).
In this case can't connect devices each other.
I saw there isn't my ip address on Internet. and think my ip is changed on internet.
Really Is it impossible to connect on internet?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x are both [private networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). This means that both devices are behind a NAT; it's impossible for one to connect directly to the other. You'll need a server on the Internet that the two can connect to and that will pass the data from one device to the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i think, NAT-PMP is good way to solve it. so do you have experience on this? My app must P2P. Looking forward to hear good response from you.